# Is there any library to draw state tree structures in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

`State tree structure (STS)`s are some special kind of diagrams, belong to `state chart`s family.

A typical `STS` could be depicted as below:

[image]

Number of the branches, state labels and cross or union symbols could be formed in any arbitrary structure, as designer intends.

Maybe `tikz-trees` would be an approximation but as I checked, I didn't feel it is able to generate something like the figure, in general.

Is there any specialized library for some sort of things in `TikZ`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version which defines a Forest style, `state tree` to format trees of this type. The assumptions, based on the example, are that

- children should be evenly spread;
- the first and last child should be equidistant from the parent;
- edges should be drawn only for the first and last child;
- the content of nodes should be typeset in maths mode.

The style may be modified if one or more of these assumptions requires amendment.

Here's the code for the tree, which is a slight adaptation of [Ignasi's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351690/):

```
\begin{forest}
  state tree,
  [x_0
    [x_1
      [x_{11}
        [x_{111}]
        [\dot{\cup}]
        [x_{112}]
      ]
      [\times]
      [x_{12}
        [x_{121}]
        [\dot{\cup}]
        [x_{122}]
      ]
    ]
    [\dot{\cup}]
    [x_2]
    [\dot{\cup}]
    [x_3
      [x_{31}]
      [\dot{\cup}]
      [x_{32}]
      [\dot{\cup}]
      [x_{33}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

`state tree` sets the style. The rest is automatic, so no need for `no edge` etc.

This produces the following result:

[image: state tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
% ateb: addaswyd o ateb Ignasi: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351690/
\forestset{%
  state tree/.style={%
    for tree={
      math content,
      parent anchor=children,
      child anchor=parent,
      tier/.option=level,
      calign=center,
    },
    where={>On>{n children}{2}}{
      for nodewalk={
        filter={children}{>On=!On=!&{n}{1}{n'}{1}}
      }{no edge}
    }{},
    before computing xy={
      where={isodd(n_children)}{
        tempdima/.process={OOOw3+d{!n=1.s}{!n'=1.s}{n children}{(##2-##1)/(##3-1)}},
        tempdimb/.option={!n=1.s},
        for children={
          s/.process={RROw3+d{tempdima}{tempdimb}{n}{##2+(##1*(##3-1))}}
        },
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  state tree,
  [x_0
    [x_1
      [x_{11}
        [x_{111}]
        [\dot{\cup}]
        [x_{112}]
      ]
      [\times]
      [x_{12}
        [x_{121}]
        [\dot{\cup}]
        [x_{122}]
      ]
    ]
    [\dot{\cup}]
    [x_2]
    [\dot{\cup}]
    [x_3
      [x_{31}]
      [\dot{\cup}]
      [x_{32}]
      [\dot{\cup}]
      [x_{33}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

you could also try with `forest`, although I don't know how to correctly distribute some children:

```
\documentclass [multi=forest, border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={math content}
[x_0
    [x_1 
        [x_{11} 
            [x_{111}] 
            [\dot{\cup}, no edge] 
            [x_{112}]]
        [\times, no edge]
        [x_{12}
            [x_{121}]
            [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
            [x_{122}]]]
    [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
    [x_2, no edge]
    [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
    [x_3
        [x_{31}]
        [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
        [x_{32}, no edge]
        [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
        [x_{33}]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: with JLDiaz suggestion, the result looks better, still not perfect, but better.

```
\documentclass [multi=forest, border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={math content}
[x_0
    [x_1 
        [x_{11} 
            [x_{111}] 
            [\dot{\cup}, no edge] 
            [x_{112}]]
        [\null, no edge]  %<-------------
        [\times, no edge]
        [x_{12}
            [x_{121}]
            [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
            [x_{122}]]]
    [\null, no edge]        %<-------------
    [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
    [x_2, no edge]
    [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
    [x_3
        [x_{31}]
        [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
        [x_{32}, no edge]
        [\dot{\cup}, no edge]
        [x_{33}]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hack-> You can insert `[\null, no edge]` in front of the `\times` node and before the first `\dot\cup` node of `x_2`.

Comment: @JLDiaz Gracias! I've updated the answer with your suggestion but I still don't understand why a `calign=center` is not working in this case.

Comment: See page 43: packing proceeds from first to last ...

Comment: @cfr I wanted to update the answer with your deleted suggestion, but you've already found a better and even automatic solution. As usual! ;-)

Comment: I deleted it because it didn't really work out. So I figured something more was required to do the job in this case. And p 43 explained why, so I replaced my suggestion with that. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @cfr No inconvenience at all! You are our `forest` expert!

Comment: Don't let Sašo hear you type that!

Answer (score 4):

A first attempt would be the following. I'm not very experienced at drawing trees, so there might be a better way to do this. However, the key point is the placing of the nodes between the children, and the `calc` library is perfect for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\rootname{root}
\newcommand{\stnode}[3]{\node at ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$) { #3 }}
\newcommand{\stnodec}[3]{\node at ($(#1.center)!0.5!(#2.center)$) { #3 }}
\newcommand{\stnoderootc}[3]{\node at ($(\rootname-#1.center)!0.5!(\rootname-#2.center)$) { #3 }}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
            level 1/.style = {sibling distance = 3cm},
            level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 2cm}
        ]
        \node (root) { $x_0$ }
            child { node { $x_1$ } 
                child { node { $x_3$ } }
                child { node { $x_4$ } }
            }
            child { node { $x_2$ } 
                child { node { $x_5$ } }
                child { node { $x_6$ } }
            }
        ;
        place the annotation nodes between the children
        \stnode{root-1.center}{root-2.center}{$\times$};
        \stnodec{root-1-1}{root-1-2}{$\times$};
        \stnoderootc{2-1}{2-2}{$\times$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can use one of the three macros (`\stnode`, `\stnodec` (*c*enter), `\stnoderootc` (automatic root node, center)) to place the annotation nodes.
The root name has to be redefined to represent the actual name of the root node. For maximum flexibility, simply use `\stnode`.

The arguments are #1:first node, #2: second node, #3: node text.

The result is the following:
[image: Result]

Obviously, the respective nodes should have the same y-placement, it will still work if this is not the case, but it will look strange.