# Removing edge label and fixing edges in forest

Tags: forest

I'm trying to make a simple hierarchy but I can't get the `forest` package to do exactly what I want. This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  nolabel/.style={% abbreviation for Edge Label
             edge label={node[midway, font=\small, text=black,
                         fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{}},
             }
          }% end of forestset
          
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    anchor=north,
    calign=first,
    s sep = 0,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.east) +(-2pt,-5pt) -| node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=20pt},
  }
[ $A$
  [$a_1$]
  [$\cdots$, nolabel]
  [$a_2$
    [$b_1^{(1)}$]
    [$b_2^{(1)}$
      [$c_1^{(2)}$]
      [$c_2^{(2)}$]
      [$c_3^{(2)}$]
    ]
    [$b_3^{(1)}$
      [$c_4^{(2)}$]
      [$c_5^{(2)}$]
      [$c_6^{(2)}$]    
    ]
  ]
  [$\cdots$, nolabel]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image]

With the `no label` style I managed to remove the circle on top of the ellipsis nodes, but I still have the edge (red circles). I could not remove it with the `no edge` option found [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400242/how-to-remove-some-edges-of-a-forest). Also, I do not understand why the lengths of the edges from the first and second levels are different (red rectangles), so I was wondering whether there is a workaround that could make these lengths equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forest already has an option for drawing straight-edged trees if we load the `edges` library. `forked edges` then enables the style for the tree. In our case, we don't want a 3-part path, however, but only a 2-part one. To eliminate the first 'leg', we can set `fork sep'=0pt`. To get the alignment correct without manual adjustment, we can then set `parent anchor=south east`.

The tree has three basic types of nodes:

1. true `phantom`s, which are inserted automatically;
2. the `\cdots` nodes, which need only the second 'leg' of the path and not the third and which don't get circles;
3. the other nodes, which need 'legs' two and three, as well as circles.

Forest already distinguishes the first type from the other two, so we need only create an option to distinguish the second from the third. I called this `phantom edge` which isn't entirely accurate. (Perhaps `partial edge` would be better?)

```
  declare boolean={phantom edge}{0},
```

This is false by default. We add `phantom edge` to the nodes which require this style.

The most straightforward way to handle the circles/no circles is to make use of the `edge label` option rather than hard-coding the circle directly into the edge specification.

```
      edge label={node[midway,fill,circle,inner sep=1.25pt]{}},
```

I started by applying this selectively, but finally decided it made more sense to apply it universally and override the application selectively later.

We use our new boolean to adjust `edge path` and `edge label` at the same time as the true phantoms are inserted. We take this out of `for tree` to make the code clearer and use `where` in place of `if` to cover the entire tree.

```
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n=1{%
        insert before={[,phantom]}
      }{%
        +content=\strut,
```

Adding `\strut` everywhere (except the real phantoms) gets us a uniform height for nodes.

```
        if phantom edge={%
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)   -- (.child anchor -| !u.parent anchor)},
```

Note the use of `edge path'` rather than `edge path` to simplify the code and avoid duplicating the standard wrapper. Note also that using `child anchor` and `parent anchor` makes the code a little bit more flexible, in case we need to make adjustments later.

```
          edge label={},
```

This removes the `edge label` (i.e. the circle node) for our second type of node.

```
        }{%
```

Nothing to do for the third type as they're just using the defaults we've already set up.

```
        },
      },
    },
```

For the separation between parents and children, I pulled the change to `l` out from `for tree`. This ensures the option is set for all nodes, including insertions, whereas the original code didn't apply it to insertions. `l sep` is also closer to what we want here than `l`, but we need to set it a bit earlier for it to be effective.

```
    before packing={%
      for tree={l sep'=-5pt},
    },
```

For reasons I don't understand, these changes were not sufficient to regularise the length of the third 'leg' of the path. However, adding `text height=1em` to `for tree` seems to work, even if I'm not sure what it is doing.

Finally, I wrapped everything into a style `tree lines` to separate the tree specification from the style used to typeset it.

```
\forestset{%
  declare boolean={phantom edge}{0},
  tree lines/.style={%
    forked edges,
    for tree={%
      fork sep'=0pt,
      math content,
      parent anchor=south east,
      anchor=north,
      calign=first,
      s sep' = 0pt,
      text height=1em,
      fit=band,
      edge label={node[midway,fill,circle,inner sep=1.25pt]{}},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n=1{%
        insert before={[,phantom]}
      }{%
        +content=\strut,
        if phantom edge={%
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)   -- (.child anchor -| !u.parent anchor)},
          edge label={},
        }{%
        },
      },
    },
    before packing={%
      for tree={l sep'=-5pt},
    },  
  },
}% end of forestset
```

[image: tree lines]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/704927/ addaswyd o gwestiwn aaragon: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598942/
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{%
  declare boolean={phantom edge}{0},
  tree lines/.style={%
    forked edges,
    for tree={%
      fork sep'=0pt,
      math content,
      parent anchor=south east,
      anchor=north,
      calign=first,
      s sep' = 0pt,
      text height=1em,
      fit=band,
      edge label={node[midway,fill,circle,inner sep=1.25pt]{}},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n=1{%
        insert before={[,phantom]}
      }{%
        +content=\strut,
        if phantom edge={%
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)   -- (.child anchor -| !u.parent anchor)},
          edge label={},
        }{%
        },
      },
    },
    before packing={%
      for tree={l sep'=-5pt},
    },  
  },
}% end of forestset
\begin{document}
          
\begin{forest}
  tree lines,
  [ A
    [a_1]
    [\cdots, phantom edge]
    [a_2
      [b_1^{(1)}]
      [b_2^{(1)}
        [c_1^{(2)}]
        [c_2^{(2)}]
        [c_3^{(2)}]
      ]
      [b_3^{(1)}
        [c_4^{(2)}]
        [c_5^{(2)}]
        [c_6^{(2)}]    
      ]
    ]
    [\cdots, phantom edge]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `nolabel` code needs to change `edge path` not `edge label`. Give the starting coordinate a name such as `ZZ`, and then use orthogonal coordinates `(ZZ-|.child anchor)`to draw the horizontal portion but not the vertical portion.

To make the vertical edges uniform on different levels, add `minimum height=6mm, inner ysep=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{
  nolabel/.style={
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.east) +(-2pt,-5pt) coordinate(ZZ) -- (ZZ-|.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  }
}% end of forestset
          
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    anchor=north,
    calign=first,
    s sep = 0,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.east) +(-2pt,-5pt) -| node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.25pt] {} (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      if n=1
        {insert before={[,phantom]}}
        {}
    },
    fit=band,
    before computing xy={l=20pt},
    minimum height=6mm, inner ysep=0pt
  }
[ $A$
  [$a_1$]
  [$\cdots$, nolabel]
  [$a_2$
    [$b_1^{(1)}$]
    [$b_2^{(1)}$
      [$c_1^{(2)}$]
      [$c_2^{(2)}$]
      [$c_3^{(2)}$]
    ]
    [$b_3^{(1)}$
      [$c_4^{(2)}$]
      [$c_5^{(2)}$]
      [$c_6^{(2)}$]    
    ]
  ]
  [$\cdots$, nolabel]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```